# Драйвер MySQL Connector ODBC - проблема с установкой

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysqlconnector

Устанавливаю драйвер mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.10 (5.1.10, 5.2.7 и даже 5.3.6 пробовал) на Windows® XP [32bit SP3] (так требует ИТ-архитектура учебного центра).
И он ни как не устанавливается.
Обновил WinInstaller, Обновил Dot.NetFramework.
Выкидывает следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем и как исправить положение?
К нему нужно ещё что-то дополнительно ставить? Не целый же mySQL-Server ставить из-за этого драйвера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ скрывался 
[здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-windows.html)!
В обзаце: "*Before installing the Connector/ODBC drivers on Windows*"

А точнее помогла установка **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010**.